# how to select what widget to include in kendo ui core?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm new to kendo ui frame work but I cant make it to work, I only want to used the kendo multiselect widget and it's giving 'extend error and multiselect is not a function'.

here is the code that i include.

```
<link href="~/Content/plugins/kendo/css/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/plugins/kendo/css/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/plugins/kendo/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/plugins/kendo/js/kendo.multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

using **kendo.ui.core.min.js** instead of core and multiselect fix my problem but I don't really need the other widget so I was avoiding using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following page lists the required files for each widget:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-editors

Keep in mind that the file order matters.

Comment: thanks. I guess I just need to use the ui.core. Btw, will there be an increase of performance if I only include the dependencies vs using ui.core?

Comment: You may experience some minor improvement in the initial load time of the scripts, but after they are cached by the browser, it will be all the same.